# Nagios showing "NOT FOUND" error

Tags: troubleshooting, nagios3

I have installed nagios package in my Ubuntu system. After opening the configuration page `localhost/nagios3` i have succesfully logged in. After that when i select any option from the left side menu it displays one of the following error

```
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/extinfo.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/showlog.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/notifications.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/history.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/status.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/outages.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/statuswrl.cgi was not found on this server.
The requested URL /cgi-bin/nagios3/trends.cgi was not found on this server.
```

`Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.7 Port 80`

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if the Apache configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/nagios3.conf`,

`/etc/apache2/conf.d/nagios3.conf or similar` has "ScriptAlias" entries like the one

below (please make sure that you have the correct file system paths):

```
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/nagios3 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3
  ScriptAlias /nagios3/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios3
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check which apache modules you have enabled - you can see them with `ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. You need the php and cgi modules enabled. You need php installed and you may need to change the mpm module you have enabled. On Ubuntu 16.04, here were the commands I had to run to get past this error:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Available modules are listed in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`.

Answer (score -2):

I found in the same situation I was missing some dependencies as the tutorials did not include them. I found one that did and it solved my issue. You should check if this installs more than you have -

```
apt-get install build-essential php5-gd wget libgd2-xpm-dev libapache2-mod-php5 apache2-utils daemon unzip
```

Comment: also don't forget apt-get install php5 !

Comment: That comment doesn't make sense.